# Expert my project visual studio c# android to as pk

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, apk

I'm working on the Android XMrain application by visual studio c # and I finished the application but I can not make it ready to install in apk format, but I see the application in the files of the project and take it and installed in the smartphone can not install it and hangs smart phone, although it is compatible with the release of Android and the device

I think that the tool in the Studio Studio is installed in it to output the applications to become ready?ا

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [doc](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/release-prep/#archive).

You must archive the project first before signing the APK.

Right click your project in solution browser and click archive button. It takes several seconds. And do not forgot to select project configuration as release. If not, the archiving will fail.

Then, the archive window will appear. This window can open from Tools menu in VS.

Now, you can signing the APK in this window. Select the project and click distribute button and follow the dialog.

If you selected the Ad Hoc options, you can take a signed APK file in the final step which can be uploaded to Android Developer Console.

Comment: add some details to the answer, the link may become invalid in the future.

Comment: Thanks for feedback dnggas90